# Getting boundary error in Postman while Uploading file using Drupal 8 Rest API

Tags: rest, file, file-upload, drupal, drupal-8

Can you please let me know how can I upload any type of file from Drupal Rest API? I am using OAuth2 for Authorization but getting Boundary error when I am uploading file from Postman. Any help please?

getting below error in Postman -

```
{ "message": "No route found that matches \"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------845557214163009053020500\"" }
```